# Can I install mono alongside .NET?

Tags: windows, .net-framework, development, mono-framework

I'm currently a .NET developer, and I want to test my applications with mono to make sure for cross-platform compatibility, but don't want to give up the offical .NET implementation.  Can I install it side-by-side on my main development PC, or do I have to use a virtual Xp environment with no .NET?

I am using Vista.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install Mono side-to-side with any .NET Framework version.

There is no interference between two of them.

Comment: I just get the package from mono.com, right?  It won't overwrite the real .NET, or encroach into it's territory (such as running .exe with .NET, not mono)?

Comment: I don't have to run the installer with odd options?  Just with no command line parameters?

Comment: Miff: You already got the answer. Mono will not interfere with .NET. You run programs with Mono by using `mono.exe program.exe`. Mono is intended as a .NET-compatible implementation of the Common Language Infrastructure and the Base Class Library. It is not intended as an .NET replacement on Windows.

Comment: @Miff: Just install it as normal application and do not worry. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Server 08 (Vista kernel) and was able to successfully install Mono, write an app using a Mono project and VB project and uninstall Mono without any issues. I had to test some ideas out and that was the easiest way to compare the two projects.